# My mouselistener is stopping my programme from launching

Tags: java, swing

On launch it tell me: <anonymous Bootleg_Paint$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener

I have no clue what this means.

I have made a few ActionListeners in the past, and according to the internet they shouls work about the same.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class Bootleg_Paint {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //The Frame
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(500, 300);
        frm.setResizable(true);
        frm.setTitle("Bootleg Paint Programme");
        frm.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setLayout(null);

        //The Panel for in the frame
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        frm.add(pnl);

        //Mouse Location Obtainer
        Point mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        int mouseX = mouse.x;
        int mouseY = mouse.y;

        //MouseListener

        boolean f = false;


        pnl.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            frm.setTitle(mouseX);
            }
        });

        for(;;){
            if(f=true){

            System.out.println(mouseX);
            System.out.println(mouseY);
            }
            


        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Try to replace MouseListener with MouseAdapter

Comment: Your compiler should tell you that even before launching.

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseListener` interface has a method  `mouseExited` which must be implemented

```
   pnl.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         frm.setTitle(mouseX);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
       //Do something or not

    }
    // implementation of the other methods of this interface https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html
   // or use an implementation which are listed in the documentation as base class

});
```

Also you have an error in `if(f=true){` it must be `if(f==true){` or simply `if(f){`

BTW:

- Names in java should be CamelCase not Snake_Case